# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: java, c++, shared-libraries

```
Exception in thread "Thread-17" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: MetadataMatching.SimXMLModule.computeStructSimXML([Ljava/lang/String;)[D
    at MetadataMatching.SimXMLModule.computeStructSimXML(Native Method)
    at MetadataMatching.SimXMLModule.<init>(SimXMLModule.java:49)
    at MetadataMatching.MatchMetadata.run(MatchMetadata.java:65)
```

> computeStructSimXML"   is a native method implemented  by C++ in "libSimXMLModule.so

Why it prompts `throw java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError` , anyone can help me ? Thank you very much?

Answer (score 3):

The library containing the native method computeStructSimXML cannot be found. You need to [add libSimXMLModule.so to your LD_LIBRARY_PATH](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/start.html#26346).